# Uniquely geodesic spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, big-list, geodesic

The purpose of this **list issue** is to better understand the class of [uniquely geodesic spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#U).
I'm looking for two different things :

- **Overclass** : for example *[geodesic space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_metric_space#G)* or *[contractible space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractible_space)*.
- **Subclass** : for example *[CAT(0) space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAT%28k%29_space)*.

Of course, I'm looking for overclass as small as possible, and subclass as large as possible. If you know just an example $E$ not contained in the union $U$ of all the subclasses cited, then $\{E\} \cup U$ is of course an acceptable subclass and analogously for the counterexamples contained in the intersection of all the overclasses cited.

Also, if you know an interesting thing not classifiable as *overclass*, *subclass* or *example*, please write, these are also welcome (for example rephrasing of the definition *if* it gives a new lighting in your opinion).

**Remark** : If you estimate it's too broad, you can first restrict to "complete", "locally compact" and "intrinsic metric" spaces (implying "geodesic"  by the [Hopf-Rinow theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem)), but I'm open to all the interesting things beyond this restriction (in particular beyond "locally compact").

**P.S.** If possible, please give a title in bold to your answer so that it will be easier to find *overclasses*, *subclasses*, *examples* and *out of category* posts.

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

(see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140019/uniquely-geodesic-and-cat0-spaces/140082#140082) of Jean-Marc Schlenker)

However, as pointed out by HenrikRüping, the CAT($0$) asumption is not necessary, you can for instance perturb the hyperbolic plane by putting a small lump of positive curvature near a point and the resulting metric will not be CAT(0) but will still be uniquely geodesic.

A deformation of the euclidean plane with soft bumps, is uniquely geodesic, but no more CAT($0$).

> What's the natural **subclass** containing this example ?

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

(see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140019/uniquely-geodesic-and-cat0-spaces/140896#140896) of Lee Mosher)

A good example is the [Teichmuller space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teichm%C3%BCller_space) of a closed oriented surface S.
It is uniquely geodesic by Teichmuller's theorem, but it is not CAT($0$).

Answer (score 3):

**Example**

(see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/140019/uniquely-geodesic-and-cat0-spaces/140891#140891) of Roberto Frigerio)

Here is another counterexample. Let us endow the Euclidean space $V=\mathbb{R}^n$ with the distance induced by the usual $\ell^p$-norm. Then, if $1<p< \infty$, then $V$ is uniquely geodesic. However, $V$ is CAT($0$) if and only if $p=2$. (The proofs of these statements are very easy; as far as I remember, they may be found in the book by Bridson and Haefliger on metric spaces of non-positive curvature).